# Grab two randomly generated divs and wrap within custom div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the two randomly generated div ID's shown below and wrap them within my custom div that I can control. Was searching around on jQuery API for solution but still no ideas.

Here's a preview of example:
[image: 2 Randomly Generated ID's + Custom Class]

Okay so as you can see, there are two `<div id="random_string"></div>` and one custom `<div class="wrap_awm"></div>`

Since I can't target the two ID's from above I have no clues how to tell jQuery, get the two div's from above wrap_awm and put them inside of the ".wrap_awm". Simple as that?

Comment: Do you just need to move the two div's immediately preceding your custom div (into you custom div)?

Comment: @travega yep, that is right!

Comment: @NenaddvL you can use the .prev() api function to get your an element's immediate preceding sibling. I have given an example below for you to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
var $wrap = $('.wrap_awm');
$wrap.prevAll(':lt(2)').appendTo($wrap);
```

It's combined with the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector to only use the first two elements.

Comment: Quite cool answer ! Works perfectly... Going to check other approaches too but I like this one. Thanks Jack.

Comment: @ErikE Sounds like a trick question :) selectors in jQuery are supposed to work on all browsers, unless you can indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

It's this simple:

```
var w = $(".wrap_awm");
w
  .prev()
  .prev()
  .addBack()
  .appendTo(w);
```

### [See a live working example at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/aJxSA/)

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks for your answer ErikE.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wrap_awm")
  .prev("div")
     .appendTo(".wrap_awm")
     .end()
  .prev("div")
     .appendTo(".wrap_awm");
```

Comment: Cool Malk... Although it only gets the first div id and wrap it within the class. Second one remain above.

Comment: Ahh - nice.  This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .prev() function in the jquery API to select the previous sibling of your custom div. You can then store that and apply the same .prev() function on it i.e:

```
var previousSibling1 = $(".wrap_awm").prev();
var previousSibling2 = $(previousSibling1).prev();
```

You now have a reference to your two previous siblings and they can be moved to your custom div.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and readable, but probably not how it *should* be done...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var prev1 = $('.wrap_awm').prev().prev();
    var prev2 = $('.wrap_awm').prev();
    $('.wrap_awm').html(prev1).append(prev2);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wH57C/)**